# disable button from submitting multiple time

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, submit, web-parts

I have created a visual webpart which means it has not form / body element in it. I have three submit buttons on the webpart. At one time, only one of there three button is visible. These button performs validation on multiple controls that are added on the webpart and then call server side methods.

Issue is that it takes time for webpart to submit and during this user can press submit button more than once which result is malfunction of the application.

I have tried jQuery solutions like adding disable attribute to submit button but it stops webpart from submitting as well.

Any help to stop multiple submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Ajax for posting your form.

And, until some processing is going on server, disable UI & show a Loading Image.

Refer:

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[UpdatePanel Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb386454.aspx)

[UpdateProgress Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb398821.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for posting. As per my understanding, if you are suggesting serve-side, then, i tried but it is too late. For client side, can you please provide more details. Please keep in mind that lots of validations applied.
Using Ajax doesn't seem to be appropriate option as we are maintaining a visual webpart.
Thanks again for reply